# Find record with specific value or lowest in other column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table for a many-to-many relation between `Objects` and `Persons`. It has the following columns:

- `Object_PersonID` (int)
- `PersonLnk` (int)
- `ObjectLnk` (int)
- `PrincipalPerson` (bit)

There are several records for each object, each row describing one of the owners for the object. Sometimes a  principle owner of the object is indicated but not always.

For a selection of objects I want to find the principal person (`PrincipalPerson=1`) if one exists, or alternatively, the person first registered (lowest value for `Object_PersonID`).
I can of course find either or all of these, but need help constructing a query that retrieves a single record for each object.

```
SELECT ObjectLnk,PersonLnk  
FROM Objects_Persons  
WHERE ObjectLnk IN (3381,5717,...,5731)
  AND ...`  
ORDER BY ObjectLnk;
```

Much obliged for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in a `CTE` with two sort-columns. If no `PrincipalPerson` exists(all are 0) you get the one with the lowest `Object_PersonID`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT o.*, p.*, -- replace * with explcit columns or aliases
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectLnk 
                                   ORDER BY PrincipalPerson DESC, Object_PersonID ASC)
    FROM Objects_Persons  
    INNER JOIN Objects o ON Objects_Persons.ObjectLnk = o.ObjectId
    INNER JOIN Persons p ON Objects_Persons.PersonLnk = p.PersonId
    WHERE ObjectLnk IN (3381,5717,...,5731)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE -- replace * with explcit columns or aliases
WHERE RN = 1
```

Maybe you even don't need the joins in this case because you have all informations you need in this relation table. Then you can omit it from the CTE. Just wanted to show how you get all informations of all related tables.

Comment: Thank you. Makes my day!